# How do i initiate directions to pin annotations from user location when the user taps the pin?

Tags: swift, xcode, uitapgesturerecognizer, mkdirection

I have a mkannotationview that generates my annotation points. I have set up user location permissions already so if the authorization is enabled, the user's location shows. I would now like for when a user clicks the pin, to generate the fastest route to the pin from the user's location (only when location authorization is enabled).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

assuming you already have a location manager created

```
var currentPlacemark: CLPlacemark? 

@IBAction func getDirectionsTapped(_ sender: Any) { //action from storyboard to viewcontroller (command + drag)
    getAddress()
}

func getAddress(){
    let overlays = mapView.overlays // these lines of code
    mapView.removeOverlays(overlays) // are to clean up your mapview when
    locationManager.stopUpdatingLocation() // a new directions request is made
    
    guard let currentPlacemark = currentPlacemark else {
        return
    }
    
    let directionRequest = MKDirections.Request()
    let destinationPlacemark = MKPlacemark(placemark: currentPlacemark)
    
    directionRequest.source = MKMapItem.forCurrentLocation()
    directionRequest.destination = MKMapItem(placemark: destinationPlacemark)
    
    directionRequest.transportType = ."[your transport type]"

    let directions = MKDirections(request: directionRequest)
    directions.calculate { (directionsResponse, error) in
        guard let directionsResponse = directionsResponse else {
            if let error = error { // unused variable
                print("Error")
        }
            return
    }
        for route in directionsResponse.routes{ //for loop to show all possible routes or let route = directionsResponse.route[0] to get first route only
            self.mapView.addOverlay(route.polyline, level: .aboveRoads) //level is optional
            self.mapView.setVisibleMapRect(route.polyline.boundingMapRect, animated: true)
        }
        
    }
    locationManager.startUpdatingLocation()
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    if let location = view.annotation as? [pointannotation name] {
    self.currentPlacemark = MKPlacemark(coordinate: location.coordinate)
    }
}

func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, rendererFor overlay: MKOverlay) -> MKOverlayRenderer {
    let render = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay as! MKPolyline)
    render.strokeColor = //choose a color
    return render
}
```